# Auto-redirect after login from https to http

Tags: java, authentication, redirect, spring-security

Hello StackOverflow community!

On login page I am getting auto redirected by Spring Security from https to http causing "Not Secure" message to be displayed to the users. Can I avoid this and remain on https after login? Please advise. My configuration is attached below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    private final LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint;
    private final SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler;
    private final UserAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;
    private final UserAuthenticationProvider authProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure( AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder )
    {
        builder.authenticationProvider( authProvider );
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception
    {
        http.csrf().disable()
            .httpBasic( hb -> hb
                    .authenticationEntryPoint( entryPoint )
            )
            .headers( h -> h
                    .frameOptions().disable()
            )
            .authorizeRequests( ar -> ar
                    .antMatchers(
                            "/newAgreement/*",
                            "/signup/*",
                            "/createStation/*",
                            "/test", "/test.htm",
                            "/iclubCss", "/iclubCss.htm",
                            "/footer", "/footer.htm",
                            "/errorMessage", "/errorMessage.htm",
                            "/favicon.ico",
                            "/eventRemoval",
                            "/trial", "/trial.htm",
                            "/classlist", "/classlist.htm",
                            "/club/getClub", "/club/getClub.htm",
                            "/club/getClubExternal", "/club/getClubExternal.htm"
                    ).permitAll()
                    .antMatchers( "/*" ).hasRole( "USER" )
            )
            .formLogin( fl -> fl
                    .loginProcessingUrl( "/performLogin" )
                    .loginPage( "/members/signin.htm" ).permitAll()
                    .failureHandler( authenticationFailureHandler )
                    .successHandler( authenticationSuccessHandler )
            )
            .logout( l -> l
                    .permitAll()
                    .invalidateHttpSession( true )
                    .logoutSuccessUrl( "/members/signin.htm?signout=1" )
                    .logoutUrl( "/members/signout.htm" )
                    .deleteCookies( "JSESSIONID" )
            )
            .sessionManagement( sm -> sm
                    .sessionFixation().newSession()
            )
        ;
    }
}
```

My user authentication success handler is

```
public class UserAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler
{
   @Override
   public void onAuthenticationSuccess( HttpServletRequest request,
                                        HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException
   {
      String url = getDefaultTargetUrl();
      if (request.getParameter("spring-security-redirect") != null) {
            url = url + request.getParameter("spring-security-redirect");
        }
        getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, url);
   }
}
```

Comment: What's your `authenticationSuccessHandler`?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- added it above

Comment: You seem to be doing a _whole lot_ of manually re-specifying defaults. Is there a specific reason for that?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- This is legacy code base that I started working on recently. I am not exactly sure why the previous team did that. Is there anything suspicious about these overloads?